# How to add a JavaScript function to h:head when inside a ui:composition?

Tags: jsf, facelets

I have an xhtml page and i want to call a javascript function in a4j:commandLink. I dont know why but the javascript method is not called. I have tried writing function into .js file using "ui:define", but still i am not able to call that method. Is this is something because it is not falling into the life cycle.

The xhtml page is as follows:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){
    alert("Hello World!");
    }
</script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputText value="Choose the produce type:" />
        <rich:inplaceSelect value="#{selectedBean.currentType}"
            valueChangeListener="#{selectedBean.valueChanged}"
            defaultLabel="Click here to select">
            <f:selectItems value="#{selectedBean.firstList}" />
            <a4j:ajax  event="change" reRender="items, label"
                ajaxSingle="true"  oncomplete="myFunction()"/>
                <a4j:log></a4j:log>
        </rich:inplaceSelect>
        <a4j:outputPanel id="label">
            <h:outputText value="Choose concrete product:"
                rendered="#{not empty selectedBean.secondList}" />
        </a4j:outputPanel>
        <a4j:outputPanel id="items">
            <rich:inplaceSelect value="#{selectedBean.currentItem}"
                rendered="#{not empty selectedBean.secondList}"
                defaultLabel="Click here to select">
                <f:selectItems value="#{selectedBean.secondList}" />
            </rich:inplaceSelect>
        </a4j:outputPanel>
    </h:panelGrid>

</h:body>
```

Comment: Which one is not called? `oncomplete="myFunction()"`? Then try a plain alert directly in it. If that is not called either, there is a problem that is not javascript related. Break down your problem!

Comment: "i want to call a javascript function in a4j:commandLink." But you've gave us code with `rich:inplaceSelect`. What is it then?

Comment: Hey i am not able to call alert() not even myFunction().

Comment: What version of RichFaces are you using? Your code is mix of 3 and 4.

Comment: Richfaces 3.3.3

Answer (score -1):

Add semicolon when you are calling java script function.

```
oncomplete="myFunction();"
```

Comment: Did you try to see if it makes a difference? As far as I know it does not

Comment: yep. i had the same problem and it toke me a while to figure it out. such a waste of time

Comment: Sure it also is a problem in plain jsf f:ajax?

Comment: nice point. i didn`t notice that. i had this problem when i was using html input type="button"